# SFSafariViewController not loading when not visible

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm trying to use a `SFSafariViewController` in the background to interact with cookies from a website. It seems that the pages is not loaded when the controller is not visible. Is that how it should be? What ways do I have to fix except than making sure the controller is always visible?

Comment: Create a new window with a low window level and add it to that.  It should load without the user ever being able to see it.

Comment: Search deeper - there was a comment here weeks ago that this view controller would not work offscreen - deliberate design by Apple. You will surely uncover more on this issue by digging.

Comment: It'd be great if you had a link to such comment. There's no such mention in the Apple doc, and Google didn't help me either.